# Stored Procedure cannot send result executed with Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm looking for a tip to understand why I'm doing wrong. Here is the facts :

I got a parameter table like this one

```
Name        Value
---------------------------
user        myusername
```

My Stored procedure does send me 1 result on SSMS using

```
EXEC    [dbo].[SP_GET_ID] @USER = 'myusername'
```

I'm using the following code on power query to get the same result, but in Excel

```
let
Param = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
USER = Param{0}[Value],

Source = Sql.Database("MYSERVER", "MYDB", [Query="EXEC [dbo].[SP_GET_ID]#(lf)@USER = '” & USER & ""'"])

in
Source
```

Param receive the data in the table you've seen above, USER gets the data myusername, and the last line send me the right column name but no result in.

```
ID
------------
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to help me get the ID ?

Huge thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Worked hard on it and got it !

```
USER = Param{0}[Value],
USERWITHQUOTE = "'" & USER & "'",

// Damit is just to show my request, how it will be sent as string to sql server
DAMIT = "Sql.Database(""MYSERVER"", ""MYDB"", [Query=""EXEC [dbo].[SP_GET_ID]#(lf)@USER = " & USERWITHQUOTE & "])",

Source = Sql.Database("MYSERVER", "MYDB", [Query="EXEC [dbo].[SP_GET_ID]#(lf)@USER = " & USERWITHQUOTE & ""])
```